# Enable Move to SD for ALL applications

Tags: java, android, xml

Lately I was wondering how you can make sure that all applications support moving to SD card. I started to do some research on the Internet and on stack overflow and came in front of this famous line in the adb shell.

```
adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2
```

My question is: is it possible to run this command from an Android application? For example something like

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell pm setInstallLocation 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Lately I was wondering how you can make sure that all applications support moving to SD card

Install to external storage is not needed on Android 3.0 and higher on most devices, as internal and external storage usually share a common partition.

> is it possible to run this command from an Android application?

`adb shell` is used from a development machine to get a shell. You do not need that when you are on the device.

That being said, the `pm` command will only modify settings like this if the process is running as root.

Comment: So if I run this code 'Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm setInstallLocation 0");' all applications will support Move to SD?

Comment: @MarioG.: I have no idea if it will work at all. It certainly would require root.